# Order of initialization in derived classes

Tags: c++, initialization, derived-class

I am trying to initialize some members of the base class through its constructor but I fail. In the following code it seems that derived class member `message` is not initialized before calling the base constructor. 
A workaround would be to have `Child(string messg_arg) : message(messg_arg), Parent(messg_arg)`, but is there any way to avoid this?

```
class Parent
{
protected:
    string something;
    Parent(string something_arg) : something(something_arg)
    {}   

}

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    string message;
    Child(string messg_arg) : message(messg_arg), Parent(message)
    {}
}
```

Comment: The order of initialisation is determined by the order that the members appear, and base classes appear before members. With that out of the way, what is it you are actually trying to accomplish? The `message` in the `Child` class shadows the message in the `Parent` class.

Comment: I was trying to construct an object in the derived class and pass it by reference to the base. Anyway, I will rethink the design.

Comment: Rather than passing stuff to the base, have the base define a function that gets the stuff from it's inheritors and force the inheritors to implement it by making the function pure virtual. `virtual Stuff & getStuff() = 0;` There are a couple potential performance considerations here, but most of the time this is a simple and safe way to get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base class constructor is called before any member constructors in the derived class. This should work fine:

```
Child(string messg_arg) : Parent(messg_arg), message(messg_arg)
{}
```

Comment: But what if I want to construct an object in the derived class and then pass it by reference to the base?

Comment: @user4168715 That's not possible, see edit. You'll have to pass it after the base is initialized.